# Doxygen: cannot find the shared library(s) 'libclang.so.6'

Tags: ubuntu, clang, doxygen, libclang

While running `doxygen` I get the following error:

```
doxygen: error while loading shared libraries: libclang.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed `doxygen` using `sudo apt install doxygen` on Ubuntu 17. In `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` I have `libclang-4.0.so.1` and `libclang-5.0.so.1` but not `libclang.so.6`.

I have tried reinstalling doxygen and clang it doesn't help.

I also tried making a symbolic link called `libclang.so.6` to the existing file `libclang-5.0.so.1` as done [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1298131/doxygen-cannot-find-the-shared-librarys-libclang-so-6-version-llvm-6-0-wh) but it leads to this error:

```
doxygen: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so.6: version `LLVM_6.0' not found (required by doxygen)
```

How to resolve this error and get doxygen working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved by using [this](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html) alternative method of installation. Follow these steps:

1. Get copy of the repository

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git
   cd doxygen
   ```
2. Build

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
   make
   ```
3. Install

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: Additionally I needed to set a symbolic link. The complete installation would be: `apt-get install -y flex bison &&
cd /tmp && git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git && cd doxygen && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. && make && make install && ln -s /usr/local/bin/doxygen /usr/bin/doxygen`

Comment: there should still be some way to install the binary distribution and link to libclang, instead of having to rebuild from source right?

Comment: to follow-up on my question, I figured it out and posted the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68446229/1898523

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 20.04, I successfully installed the binary distribution from https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#srcbin (`doxygen-1.9.1.linux.bin.tar.gz`
which is "compiled using Ubuntu 20.04 and dynamically linked against libclang version 9"). Then by using `apt-file` program, I was able to find and install each missing library as follows:

```
$ doxygen --version
doxygen: error while loading shared libraries: libclang-9.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ apt-file search libclang-9.so.1
libclang1-9: /usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/libclang-9.so.1
libclang1-9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-9.so.1

$ sudo apt install libclang1-9
(...)

$ doxygen --version
doxygen: error while loading shared libraries: libclang-cpp.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ apt-file search libclang-cpp.so.9
libclang-cpp9: /usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/libclang-cpp.so.9
libclang-cpp9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-cpp.so.9

$ sudo apt install libclang-cpp9
(...)

$ doxygen --version
1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b)
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly add this to your repo

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/artful/ llvm-toolchain-artful-6.0 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/artful/ llvm-toolchain-artful-6.0 main
```

now run the following

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
apt-get install clang-6.0 lldb-6.0 lld-6.0
```

--source http://apt.llvm.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can also install doxygen using:

```bash
sudo apt install doxygen
```

It will install all dependencies by itself.